# Ubuntu 10 repositories help

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, repository

Looks like not all the files on my repositories any more as you see below.

```
Failed to fetch http://update.onlinehome-server.info/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libsndfile/libsndfile1_1.0.21-2ubuntu0.10.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Just wondering whats the best ones to add that are safe and will not break my web server? I'm guessing I add them to bottom of the sources.list

Cheers

would it be fine to add to get it to work?

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted 
deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security main restricted 
deb http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted 
deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security main restricted 
deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
```

Comment: A stupid question: did you run `sudo apt-get update` before trying to install something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, if individual packages are giving 404s, your Packages lists are out of date and you need to run `apt-get update` to refresh them.

If that isn't the case, then the repo you're using has probably gone away or is otherwise badly mismanaged.  In general, I only have two sorts of repos in my `sources.list`:

- The ones for the distribution and release I'm using (regular and security updates); and
- A local repo containing rebuilds and backports of packages for which I'm running updated or locally-modified versions, which I've built myself.

Random repositories create far too much risk to be a professionally prudent option.

Comment: I've done a apt-get update and still the same error

Comment: Oh well, the repo's probably gone to god.  Why are you using such a random crackpot repo anyway?

Comment: god knows... I'm just a little lost on the best way to add new ways to the list for the right version of ubuntu. What are the best to add for a live production server? Cheers

Comment: would it be fine to add ###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted 
deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security main restricted 
deb http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted 
deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security main restricted 
deb-src http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted

Comment: "god knows"?  Bugger that, *you* should know, *you're* the admin.  The best to add for a live production server are those I listed in my answer.